# <Class list> object and xslxwriter error

Tags: python, data-structures, typeerror, nested-lists

Want to create a script which downloads the financial key ratios from morningstar. I use from github xlsxwriter and good-morning modules,but have an issue(new to python). The kr_ratios 's data structure is . I cannot convert it to plain  type and as a result cannot write .xlsx file. Also, how can I find the names of sublists in kr_ratios? I Have the following code:

```
import good_morning as gm
import csv
import xlsxwriter

with open('greekstocks.csv', newline='') as File:  
  reader = csv.reader(File)
  dataa=[]
  for i in reader:
    dataa.extend(i)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Financials_GR.xlsx')

for tick in dataa[1:2]:
   kr = gm.KeyRatiosDownloader()
   kr_ratios = kr.download(tick)
   worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
   worksheet1.write('A1:FG:1000',kr_ratios)


workbook.close()
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'list'> in write()
```

Comment: Have you spent time pouring over the `good_morning` documentation?  did you try to get it to work for just one `tick` before iterating over `dataa`?

Comment: [Example of Downloading Key Ratios from MorningStar](https://github.com/petercerno/good-morning#example-of-downloading-key-ratios-from-morningstar). `kr_ratios` is a list containing [Pandas DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - each Pandas has a *builtin* method to write [to a csv file](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) : and some *builtin* [excel methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files)  You will need to rewrite your code to work with the DataFrames.